# Chapter number aligned with text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chapters

I have a two side book and this is a new chapter. And this is the code I have to made this title.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
%-----------------------------------------%
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {}
  {\llap{\color{gray}\chapterNumber\thechapter
   \hspace{10pt}\vline}} %Espacio hacia la izquierda del número
  {10pt} %espacio del texto hacia derecha
  {\formatchaptertitle}

\newcommand{\formatchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-10pt}{\raggedright\huge\scshape#1}}

\newcommand{\chapterNumber}{%
  \fontsize{60}{60}\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}}

%----------------------------%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Auditoría}
\end{document}
```

The thing is that I want to align the 6. with the text, the inner margin must be 3cm and the 6 breaks this rule. So how can I move the 6 and the text more to the center?

The pictures shows my question better.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your code does not compile. You missed some package.

Comment: Sorry, I added the packages which are {titlesec} and {xcolor,lipsum}

Comment: @joudaon I have updated and corrected the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `\llap` or better, do as @egreg suggests in the comments below, replace '\llap' with an `\mbox{}` to avoid potentially future problems.

When we move the chapter number to the right, we also have to correct the size of the `\parbox` containing the chapter name to avoid long chapter names sticking out from the outer margin (see fig 2). First we have to correct for the 10pt on both side of the vertical line, then we have to measure the width of chapter number and reduce that width. As @egreg point out, we measure the width by putting the chapter number in `\sbox0` and withdraw `\wd0` from the with of the parbox:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
%-----------------------------------------%
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {}
  {\mbox{\color{gray}\chapterNumber\thechapter
   \hspace{10pt}\vline}} %Espacio hacia la izquierda del número
  {10pt} %espacio del texto hacia derecha
  {\formatchaptertitle}

\newcommand{\formatchaptertitle}[1]{\sbox0{\chapterNumber\thechapter}% measure the width
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt-\wd0}{\raggedright\huge\scshape#1}}% reduce the width of the parbox

\newcommand{\chapterNumber}{%
  \fontsize{60}{60}\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}}

%----------------------------%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Auditoría}
\end{document}
```

Fig 1

[image]

Fig 2

[image]

Comment: I'd be more on the safe side and use `\mbox` *instead* of `\llap`, but this may be good as well.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I did not understand you comment. I suggested removing the `\llap` command. Do you recommend to *replace* `\llap` with an `\mbox{}`? I appreciate any correction (I prefer that the OP gets the *best* advise., not only one that functions) :).

Comment: @Sveinung Yes, that's what I meant. But it's probably just a useless precaution.

Comment: @Sveinung Also `\llap` is not really the best tool, because a change to the internals of `titlesec` might lead to spectacular failures; better would be `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}`. Similarly, the same change to the internals of `titlesec` would put `\color` in vertical mode, which is in the list of dangerous-things-best-not-do-them. Either `\textcolor{gray}{...}` or `\mbox{\color{gray}...}` would avoid the problem.

Comment: @egreg When I look at the definition of \formatchaptertitle, it seems that the parbox will be to wide, the \parbox should have been shortened by the width of \chapterNumber, not only by 10pt. Do you agree? But how to messure that width and use it in the \dimexpr{}

Comment: `\sbox0{typeset the chapter number}`, then `\wd0` contains the width.