# How to change style in titlesec heading

Tags: titlesec

I am working with code that I found here [Chapter number aligned with text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220052/chapter-number-aligned-with-text) but have some questions on how to change it.

I would like the Chapter title to be 'as written', so capital and small letters.
Furthermore I would like to make the chapter number 'normal' looking. Can anyone help`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%-----------------------------------------%
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {}
  {\mbox{\color{black}\chapterNumber\thechapter
   \hspace{10pt}\vline}} %Espacio hacia la izquierda del número
  {10pt} %espacio del texto hacia derecha
  {\formatchaptertitle}

\newcommand{\formatchaptertitle}[1]{\sbox0{\chapterNumber\thechapter}% measure the width
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt-\wd0}{\raggedright\huge\scshape#1}}% reduce the width of the parbox

\newcommand{\chapterNumber}{%
  \fontsize{60}{60}\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Introduction}

\end{document}
´´´
```

Comment: What do you mean a ‘normal looking‘ chapter number? And for the title, you don't want small caps, only uppercase for the initial letter of the words in the title?

Comment: By 'normal' looking I mean that it should look the same as the number in front of \section just bigger. For the title I want the letters 'as written', so when I type 'Introduction', I want 'Introduction' and not 'INTRODUCTION'.

Comment: Your  code yields neither, but small caps (except the initial letter, which is uppercase)

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpocH.png) is how it looks when I compile it

Comment: I have the same. This is a title in small caps.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not perfect, but what I want is the 1 | INTRODUCTION to look like 1 | Introduction

Comment: If this is called 'small caps', then I think I do not want small caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose this, after somewhat simplifying the code. Note the default input encoding is now utf8, so it's not necessary to load `inputenc`. See it it suits your needs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm, vmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%-----------------------------------------%
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\raggedright\bfseries}
  {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter
   \hspace{8pt}\vline width1.2pt} %Espacio hacia la izquierda del número
  {10pt} %espacio del texto hacia derecha
  {\huge}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the chapter number in the margin;, you can use `\llap`, like this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%[block]
  {\raggedright\bfseries}
  {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}\llap{\thechapter
   \hspace{6pt}\vline width1.2pt}} %Espacio hacia la izquierda del número
  {10pt} %espacio del texto hacia derecha
  {\huge}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} I get some errors in my full document, but with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} it looks good, too!

Comment: is it also possible to use the look of the number from 'my code' with your version? I would like to try out both, but I do not really understand where the look comes from

Comment: Yes: insert `\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}` between `\selectfont` and `\thechapter`.

Comment: Thank you, this works nearly perfectly. But now there is one problem with the simplification of the code. Before the title was aligned with the first row on the left and the text on the right. Like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRR2z.png). But now the second row is starting all left, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORMWY.png)

Comment: That is because you used the `block` style. I've modified this in the answer, using the `hang` style (which, incidentally, is the default). Another possibility would be to have the number in the margin.

Comment: How can I put the number in the margin?

Comment: Please  see the edit.